# How to I get Ubuntu installation to recognize my Mac OS?

Tags: dual-boot, macbook

I have a late 2013 Macbook Pro running Yosemite 10.10.13.  I installed 14.04.2 LTS on a USB and am able to boot into Ubuntu. I left 100 Gb of free space on my 1Tb Apple SSD for Ubuntu. When I go thru the installation process it does not show the option to install alongside MacOS because it apparently does not see it.  How can I get it to see the OS?

Comment: Just choose the `Something Else` option and select the drive you made.

Comment: thanks I tried that, but when I select the "free space" partition I get "no root file system is defined". The only options disk utility gives me for a new partition are: 1) Mac OS Extended (Journaled), 2) Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive Journaled), or 3) Free space. If I select either of the first two options ubuntu says something like "no partition available". If I select "Free Space" it says no root file system is defined".

Comment: You need to double click the partition, select the ext4 filesystem option, select to format it and do `/` as the mount point.

Comment: Sorry. In the Ubuntu Install, when you choose Something Else.

Comment: Thanks, are you sure you're talking about Disk Utility on OS X? Double clicking does nothing on mine. Perhaps I should use OSXFUSE? This would be strange though because it appears Ubuntu should install without having to resort to 3rd party software.

Comment: yes that did it. double click. never tried it before!  thanks!!